# Custom Cell sending one coordinate to all locations,

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have A Viewcontroller with a tableview inside, which creates a custom cell containing information from my json and when the cell is taped, it sendS information to another view which shows the business location in a map, and the location name on the annotation. My problem is the cell sendS the information but on the map it shows the same latitude and longitude coordinates for every cell tapped and I can't seem to understand why.

Here is what I have:

this is my custom cell view controller:

```
import UIKit

class BusinessImgTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var businessImg:     UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var businessNameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var distanceLbl:     UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()



    let view = UIView(frame: businessImg.frame)
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    let arrayColors:Array<AnyObject> = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]

    gradient.frame = view.frame
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradient.colors = arrayColors


    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    businessImg.addSubview(view)
    businessImg.bringSubview(toFront: view)
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

this is the viewContoller with the tableview and information[won't add json because I know the problem is not there]:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var businessTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuBTN:           UIBarButtonItem!

               var businessName:      String!
               var currentLocation:   CLLocationCoordinate2D?




var BusinessInfo = [Business]()    

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestLocation()



    }

    businessTableView.delegate = self
    businessTableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



struct Business {

    let name: String
    let image: NSURL
    let city: String
    let distance: String
    let businessLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error){

    // Handle errors here
}
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return BusinessInfo.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessImgTableViewCell

    let businessInformation = BusinessInfo[indexPath.row]
    let imgdirectory = businessInformation.image

    let urlString: URL = imgdirectory as URL
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: urlString)

    let myDistance = Double(businessInformation.distance)

        cell.businessImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        cell.businessNameLbl.text = businessInformation.name
        cell.distanceLbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", myDistance!) + " mi."
        cell.distanceLbl.sizeToFit()
        cell.businessNameLbl.sizeToFit()
        currentLocation = businessInformation.businessLoc



    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! BusinessImgTableViewCell


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mydestination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "businessInfoView") as! BusinessInfoViewController

    mydestination.businessCoor = currentLocation
    mydestination.businessName = currentCell.businessNameLbl.text
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(mydestination, animated: true)



}
```

and this is the view showing the map

```
class BusinessInfoViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var businessLoc: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var backBTN: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var backbtn: UIButton!

var businessCoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

   var businessName: String!





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(businessCoor.latitude, businessCoor.longitude)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(initialLocation, span)

    businessLoc.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = initialLocation
    annotation.title = businessName

    businessLoc.addAnnotation(annotation)

    self.businessLoc.delegate = self


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: In `didSelect` you need to get the location associated with the selected row. `currentLocation` Is the location associated with the last cell displayed

Comment: can you show me how to do it, i tried many ways and can't seem to find the solution, thank you

Comment: The same as you do in `cellForRowAt`; use `BusinessInfo[indexPath.row]`

Comment: that wokeeed thank you so much, had days trying to figure this out, yet it was so simple thank you man

Comment: can't upvote, need more rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAt` you are using the property `currentLocation`, which is the location for the last cell that was provided by `cellForRowAt:`.  What you need to do is access the `BusinessInfo` array at `indexPath.row`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! BusinessImgTableViewCell


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mydestination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "businessInfoView") as! BusinessInfoViewController
    let business = BusinessInfo[indexPath.row]
    mydestination.businessCoor = business.businessLoc
    mydestination.businessName = business.name
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(mydestination, animated: true)

}
```

FYI your array should be `businessInfo`, not `BusinessInfo` - variables, constants and properties should start with a lower case letter, not an uppercase letter.